# "Integration" between Rails' ActiveRecord and Java's Hibernate

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, hibernate, activerecord

Hi everybody: let me do a bit of "concept mining" here: I am involved in mantaining/extending an application whose functionality is distributed across several servers. For example, we have a machine running the ApplicationServer, another running the DataServer and so on.

This application has a Web Interface. The current UI is totally implemented in Java, and in a way that makes adding new functionality hard. One of my goals is extending this interface, and we're considering shifting the whole thing to another platform, like Rails, for example.

**Problem being, the database that is manipulated by the UI (possibly Rails in the future) is also manipulated by ApplicationServer (Java).**

So, my main question is: both Rails and Java can access databases through their own ORM (ActiveRecord for Rails and Hibernate or similar for Java). **Is there any way to guarantee that the mappings are consistent?***

Even if the answer is a hard "no", I'd also like to hear your thoughts on how you'd approach this scenario.

I hope the question is clear enough, but warn me if it isn't and I'll edit accordingly. =D

***Edit:** per request, I'm extending this explanation: what I mean is, how to make sure things don't break when someone needs to add a new field to the database and edits the Hibernate mapping because of it? I know that Rails "guesses" the entity attributes pretty much by itself (making things easier), but I was wondering if there was some "magical way" to "connect" the ActiveRecord directly to the Hibernate mapping.

Comment: What do you mean by "guaranteeing mapping consistency"?

Comment: Added a comment to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your case and how important it is to actually ensure that things won't break. I would probably code the Rails app to do its best, and then write a good set of db integration test cases for Rails to test against breakage.

Because Hibernate needs a mapping conf whereas Rails uses the database layout directly, it's best to do the db changes on Hibernate/mapped Java class side and then run the test suite on Rails side after changes.

Answer (score 1):

this might be coming too late to the party, but ActiveJDBC is an ActiveRecord- like implementation in Java which reads metadata and configures self pretty much the same as ActiveRecord: http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using DataMapper instead of ActiveRecord.  DataMapper and Hibernate following roughly the same pattern so the mappings would be similar. Also, DataMapper defines the mapping in the class itself rather than figuring it out from the model.  This is much closer to Hibernate and you could probably write a simple hbm to dm converter and just eval the output at the top of your model classes. If you didn't design your original data model with Rails in mind, none of the convention over configuration standards are likely to be there; with DataMapper, the default seems to be to map properties and relationships like Hibernate.

Another idea: if you use the Hibernate annotations instead of xml mapping, maybe you could JRuby as the bridge to build the Ruby model from the Java one.

But either way, if you have good tests, it should be obvious when a data model change break something.